# Set post page for custom post type for Wordpress Admin Post Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently on WordPress **5.6.2** and developing a plugin.

I need to set a custom template for a custom post type.

My custom post type is `reseller_r_limit`.

My current page when I click on `Add new` button, it looks like `http://localhost/project/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=reseller_r_limit`.

I have referred to many similar questions and I got to know that we need to use `single-{post_type}.php`. I did so and my plugin folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
reseller program 
   --> reseller_program.php
   --> templates
     --> single-reseller_r_limit.php
```

The content under `single-reseller_r_limit.php` looks like below with a simple echo message:

```
<?php

echo "Hey";
```

I registered the `post_type` using `register_post_type` as below:

```
add_action('init','reseller_limit_post_type');

function reseller_limit_post_type(){
    register_post_type('reseller_r_limit',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __('Reseller Redeem Limits'),
                'singular_name' => __('Reseller Redeem Limits'),
            ),
            'public'      => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => false,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'rewrite'             => false,
            'query_var'           => false,
        )
    );
}
```

The issue is I am still not able to see the **Hey** when I click on `add new` button which means Wordpress is still unable to find the template file and it directly takes me to adding a new usual post. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: _“Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?”_ - in assuming these templates had anything to do with _backend_ functionality, like adding posts? These are the _frontend_ templates.

Comment: @CBroe I actually mean the I want to override the textboxes on this page with my template. https://imgur.com/a/78OV1uS They definitely look backend stuff for me.

Comment: `'public' => false` is also set to make them invisible to the frontend.

Comment: What you want to do there, is backend stuff, yes - but that doesn’t change the fact, that this template system wasn’t meant to work there in the first place. If you want to change any _functionality_ in the backend (add new fields, or anything like that), then you need to use the hooks provided, check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8521 for starters.

Comment: @CBroe I actually went through them but they don't seem to help much. I am wondering how woocommerce did it for coupons. Yes, I am definitely a starter in Wordpress.

Comment: Then google “wp create custom admin pages”, you should find plenty.

Comment: @CBroe I see what you mean now. Those were customizations to how a frontend user could see stuff. I will check with the custom admin pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by `@CBroe` in the comments, `single-{post_type}.php` files are only for frontend templates.

---

If you want to add the custom meta fields to your custom post type in the *admin panel* inside, you need to do the following:

- Use `add_meta_boxes` hook to add your custom fields like below:

  ```
  <?php

  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reseller_meta_boxes',10,2);

  function reseller_meta_boxes($post_type, $post){
        if($post_type == "reseller_r_limit"){
            add_meta_box( 'reseller-limit-country', 'Reseller Country', 'reseller_limit_country_field' );
            // all other fields
        }
  }

  function reseller_limit_country_field( $post ){
     $reseller_country = get_post_meta($post->ID,'reseller_country',true);
     $countries_obj = new WC_Countries();
     $countries = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
     echo '<label for="reseller_country">Reseller Country:</label>';

     woocommerce_form_field('reseller_country', array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter something'),
        'options'     => $countries,
        'default' => empty($reseller_country) ? 'GB' : $reseller_country
       )
     );
  }
  ```
- To override the usual post fields you can play with the `supports` key's values in `register_post_type` method. If you want none of the standard post fields given by
  wordpress, you can simply pass an empty value in an array like below:

  ```
  register_post_type('reseller_r_limit',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __('Reseller Redeem Limits'),
                'singular_name' => __('Reseller Redeem Limits'),
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new limit'
            ),
            'public'      => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => false,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'hierarchical'  => false,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'query_var' => false,
            'supports' => array('') // here, or if you want some, you can have like array('title','editor','author','excerpt') etc
        )
    );
  ```